# Bépo keyboard layout has been sabotaged in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-17.10

I've been using the [Bépo](http://bepo.fr) keyboard layout for years in Ubuntu, labelled as "French (Bepo, ergonomic, Dvorak way)".

Since upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 (Artful Aardvark), I now have to use Ctrl+Shift+V to paste, instead of Ctrl+V. This is unintuitive and I'd like to change it back, but I'm not sure how to revise it. In the system settings, there are keyboard shortcuts for starting the terminal etc, but nothing about sabotaging the effect of buttons such as Ctrl. There are no shortcuts listed for copying or pasting.

I suspect that Ubuntu itself has used a faulty key file, as I recall having a similar problem with Windows a while ago, having to mess around with Microsoft's Keyboard Layout Creator.

Comment: http://bepo.fr/wiki/Touches_mortes

Answer (score 0):

In Windows I'd experienced a phenomenon where the right alt key had been implemented as ctrl+alt or something along those lines, so I figured that maybe in Ubuntu, the OS was using an odd combination, capturing a potential combination for something unrelated.

I went into the keyboard settings and disabled lots of various combinations that I don't use; then «paste» is working again! There was nothing with a V, so this seems odd. Maybe there were side-effects happening somewhere along the way.

Comment: Oh today it wasn't working again. Maybe it was always working yesterday after I'd started my computer (I turn it off every day). If this is an intermittent issue, I guess it would be the fault of the hardware?